# Scala Quill - queries always dynamic

Tags: scala, quill.io

I am always getting dynamic queries in Quill, even with simplest query I get dynamic query compiler warning log:

> type DbContext = PostgresAsyncContext[Literal]
>
> val db: DbContext = new PostgresAsyncContext(Literal, "db.default")
>
> import db._
>
> implicit val implicitDbSchemaMetaUser: db.SchemaMeta[User]
>    = schemaMeta [User] ("users")
>
> val users:Future[List[User]] = run(query[User])

Comment: Please provide full example.

Answer (score 2):

Removing type annotation from implicitDbSchemaMetaUser solved it:

> implicit val implicitDbSchemaMetaUser = schemaMeta [User] ("users")